# comparing fairness in single processor vs multiprocessor

Tags: computer-science, cpu-architecture, processor, multiprocessor, fairness-indicators

The guarded-command looping construct

```
do
Condition ⇒ Command
...
Condition ⇒ Command
od
```

involves nondeterministic choice, as explained in the text. An important theoretical concept related to potentially nonterminating nondeterministic computation
is fairness. If a loop repeats indefinitely, then a fair nondeterministic choice must
eventually select each command whose guard is true. For example, in the loop

```
do
true ⇒ x := x+1
true ⇒ x := x-1
od
```

both commands have guards that are always true. It would be unfair to execute `x := x+1` repeatedly without ever executing `x := x-1`.
Most language implementations are
designed to provide fairness, usually by providing a bounded form. For example,
if there are `n` guarded commands, then the implementation may guarantee that
each enabled command will be executed at least once in every `2n` or `3n` times
through the loop.
Because the number `2n` or `3n` is implementation dependent,
though, programmers should assume only that each command with a `true` guard
will eventually be executed.

Is fairness easier to provide on a single-processor language implementation
or on a multiprocessor?

Comment: We require you to provide proper attribution for the original source of all copied material: https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Answer (score 0):

Most languages have a serial model of execution, like machine code, not executing each statement in parallel with arbitrary ratios of executions.  For example in C,

```
  for (int i=0; i<10 ; i++){
     if (true) puts("hello");
     if (true) puts("world");
  }
```

You'll always get output like

```
hello
world
hello
world
```

in that order.

---

Fair (or at least non-starving) thread-level parallelism is pretty easy on single or multi-core machines, with pre-emptive multi-tasking.  Most languages with a thread model are designed around pre-emptive thread scheduling, where one thread running an infinite loop (even with no system calls) won't starve other threads.

Multi-core is harder to implement a correct OS for (e.g. you need locking, not just disabling interrupts), but does allow more threads to be running at once.